# Unable to run julia 1.7.3 kernel on jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I tried using *Julia 1.7.3 kernel* with *Jupiter lab* and VS code but had no luck. I got the following error in the console when I clicked on the run in the Jupiter lab cell. I have installed `ipykernel` and added IJulia to Pkg. I don't think the problem is in that.

```
    in expression starting at /home/rohit/.julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/kernel.jl:1
[I 2022-11-15 10:54:57.314 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
[ Info: Precompiling IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a]
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Parsers does not have SnoopPrecompile in its dependencies:
- If you have Parsers checked out for development and have
  added SnoopPrecompile as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
  environment's manifest file, try `Pkg.resolve()`.
- Otherwise you may need to report an issue with Parsers
Stacktrace:
  [1] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:980
  [2] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [3] include(x::String)
    @ Parsers ~/.julia/packages/Parsers/bEa0b/src/Parsers.jl:1
  [4] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/Parsers/bEa0b/src/Parsers.jl:393
  [5] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [6] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
  [7] top-level scope
    @ none:1
  [8] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
  [9] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [10] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/rohit/.julia/packages/Parsers/bEa0b/src/precompile.jl:1
in expression starting at /home/rohit/.julia/packages/Parsers/bEa0b/src/Parsers.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile Parsers [69de0a69-1ddd-5017-9359-2bf0b02dc9f0] to /home/rohit/.julia/compiled/v1.7/Parsers/jl_7qWIcC.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base ./Base.jl:418
  [8] include(x::String)
    @ JSON ~/.julia/packages/JSON/NeJ9k/src/JSON.jl:3
  [9] top-level scope
    @ ~/.julia/packages/JSON/NeJ9k/src/JSON.jl:11
 [10] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
 [11] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [13] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [14] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [15] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/rohit/.julia/packages/JSON/NeJ9k/src/Parser.jl:1
in expression starting at /home/rohit/.julia/packages/JSON/NeJ9k/src/JSON.jl:3
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile JSON [682c06a0-de6a-54ab-a142-c8b1cf79cde6] to /home/rohit/.julia/compiled/v1.7/JSON/jl_CxGVlg.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:997
  [7] include
    @ ./Base.jl:418 [inlined]
  [8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:1318
  [9] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [10] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [11] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:453
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at /home/rohit/.julia/packages/IJulia/AQu2H/src/IJulia.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile IJulia [7073ff75-c697-5162-941a-fcdaad2a7d2a] to /home/rohit/.julia/compiled/v1.7/IJulia/jl_f8oPcc.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1466
 [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1410
 [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1120
 [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1013
 [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
```

In VS code, nothing happens when I run it and I see no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons might differ, depends on what you're using (conda, etc.). I recently installed Julia 1.8.2 on Ubuntu and it opens with jupyter via the following procedure (I had Jupyter installed on my laptop):

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add(“IJulia”)
using IJulia
installkernel("Julia")
```

If you have not-a-Linux machine (I suspect it is Mac), I strongly recommend to check these answers:

- [Julia's website](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-kernel-doesnt-connect-when-using-jupyter/86052) and [one more](https://julialang.github.io/IJulia.jl/stable/manual/installation/#Installing-IJulia)
- [Post from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306073/cant-run-julia-in-jupyter-notebook) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071591/kernel-error-using-julia-on-jupyter-notebook)

Good luck!